# Angular i18n for attributes with select

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-i18n

I have an element I want to translate using i18n from angular. The part that I want to translate is the matTooltip but the value is a select. I know that I have to use `i18n-matTooltip` to make it work. I should use this syntax `<span i18n>The author is {gender, select, male {male} female {female} other {other}}</span>` from the docs but I get an error doing so.

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Missing expected : at column 9 in [{section.addTooltip, 
select, test {test} test2 {test2} test3 {test3}}] in 
ng:///AppModule/TestComponent.html@34:72 ("
    </div>
```

This is what my element looks like:

```
<button mat-flat-button (click)="click()" 
    [matTooltip]="{section.addTooltip, select, test {test} test2 {test2} test3 
    {test3}}" matTooltipPosition="above" i18n-matTooltip>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: @can you share your component.ts code?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue, to interpolate i18n into `matTooltip` you have to create a hidden HTML element to perform i18n in and pass `reference.innerText` as tooltip value (found [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/10165#issuecomment-368983097)). This looks like a hack, but Angular Components team [has decided](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8357) not to support `ng-template` as a valid input value.

Unlike `ng-template`, the hidden element won't always stay unnoticeable, for example `mat-select` trigger value [uses](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/e6afdbb9db80b6b5e8175a2873e60176cbcaab8f/src/material/core/option/option.ts#L141) `mat-option`'s `textContent`, so if you put tooltip or element with tooltip into `mat-option`, whole tooltip text will be visible in trigger. This can be worked around with a `mat-select-trigger` and custom trigger text.

[See working example at StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/56726037-answer).

```
<button
  [matTooltip]='template.innerText'
  (click)='changeValue()'
>Click to change value</button>
Value: {{value}}
<template
  #template
  i18n='@@foo'
>Value is {value, select, true {truthy} false {falsy} }</template>
```

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  value = 'true'
  changeValue() {
    this.value = this.value === 'true' ? 'false' : 'true'
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. I noticed that the `mat-select` value inserts a `span` in the DOM to represent the `mat-option` value itself. Do I also need to use a `#template` var like your stackblitz sample, or can I use this ICU Select syntax directly `<mat-option    i18n="@@genderValue"><span>{Gender, select, male {male} female {female} other {other}}</span></mat-option>`